# DATETIME2FROMPARTS alternatives for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, date-format, datetime

I am trying to part a datetime value and build it together removing minutes, seconds and so on. I want the values to be hourly.

Usually this works on a SQL Server 2012 machine:

```
DATETIME2FROMPARTS( DATEPART(year, datum), DATEPART(month, datum), DATEPART(day, datum), DATEPART(hour, datum), 0, 0, 0, 0) as dtHour
```

But unfortunately in SQL Server 2008 it does not! Which function do I need, to fulfill the same job?

I also looked up this reference: [Date&Time functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) but this were all only SQL Server 2012 compliant.

Comment: The link you reference can display other versions of SQL Server, for instance this is for 2008: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it a bit shorter.

```
dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, datum), 0)
```

This calculates the number of hours between `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`  and `datum` and adds that value to `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

Comment: nice : ) thank you! ps: i tried to upvote, but unfortunately SO doesnt allow me to upvote, because i dont have 15 rep. points

Comment: You now have more than enough rep!